# How to prove exponential inequalities

Tags: calculus

I know that it is at least in theory to prove inequalities of the form $\mathrm{e}^x>y$: Just sum enough many first terms from the Taylor's series. But how one can prove inequalities of the form $\mathrm{e}^x<y$? Do we have to estimate the terms in Taylor series or are there other methods?

Comment: I think this question is too general for a meaningful answer.

Comment: Are you assuming $x\ge 0$?  I ask because if $x<0$ then the Taylor series is alternating, so truncating it doesn't necessarily give a lower bound.

Comment: I'm looking a general method to approximate $e^x$ with its error for all real numbers $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is the kind of thing you're after: if $n > |x|$ then
$$ \left(1+\frac xn\right)^n \le e^x \le \left(1-\frac xn\right)^{-n} $$

Update: OK, since you accepted this, I guess it's the kind of thing you're after.  Here's a sketch of a proof that it's correct: First, the LHS.  In fact we often define $e^x = \lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac xn)^n$, so it's enough to show that this sequence is increasing (for $n>|x|$).  This follows from the AM/GM inequality applied to $n$ copies of $1+\frac xn$ and one $1$.  The RHS then follows by applying the LHS to $-x$ in place of $x$.